# UIWebView reuse

Tags: ios, uiwebview, load, reusability

I want to use UIWebview in different view controllers,but i don't want these view controller to reload the web page, in another way, I want a UIWebview to load the page once,and used it anywhere.
SO I want to create a web view and load the webpage in a singleton way. 
My question is : is this possible or appropriate?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's type of your html to present ? Is it static HTML content or dynamic URL source?

**For static HTML content**

I suggest you to create prefer HTML file and load them directly.

```
NSString *htmlContent = @"Your Static HTML Code";
NSData *htmlData = [htmlContent dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

if (htmlData) {
    NSString *_path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSURL *_baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:_path];
    [self.BottomWebView loadData:htmlData MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:_baseURL];
}
```

**For dynamic HTML content base on your URL source**

When you have loaded the data in the first request , you can store them with NSData that can be the properties in your singleton class.  Of course, you can call them any where, any ViewController to get your data and load them in your UIWebview with once connection.

hope it helps you !

Comment: thanks for your help, I have tried use the UIWebView in a singleton way and that works.

Comment: If you like this answer , I'm glad to hear your acceptance click